# how to get the size of product to the cart page

Tags: magento, size, cart

I have size of product (XS, XL, ...).

I want add column in cart table Size, where show sizes of products.

I added SKU in this table $_item->getSku(); This works.
But $_item->getSize(); not works. Please, help me.

Comment: I'm trying also
$_item->getProduct()->getData('size');
This not works too

Answer (score 0):

try adding `->addFieldToSelect('*')`, it'll add every attribute associated with your products in the returning data, you can replace the * with the attribute code of the attribute your trying to display

problem is, it'll return integers that are used in either eav_attribute_option or eav_attribute_option_value (not sure why there's 2 different tables, one has values and one has sort order, it's not like Magento even links a value to 2 options), however if you use the following code

```
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter('ATTRIBUTE_CODE')->getFirstItem();

$sizeValues = array();

// populates sizevalue array with data
foreach ($attributeOptions as $key => $value)
{
    $sizeValues[$value['value']] = $value['label'];
}
```

you get an array of values with their index's being that of that it returned in your collection